# Postfix using a RESTful API for authentication

Tags: postfix, authentication, sasl

Is it possible to connect Postfix to a RESTful API to validate password/username?

What I imagine an ideal scenario is if Postfix handled the LOGIN or PLAIN methods (behind TLS only, but that is besides the point for this question) and passed along the username and password to a URL for validation.

The goal is to hook up Postfix to a legacy PHP application which stores password hashes in a complicated way that makes it impossible to hook up to the database directly.

Answer (score 2):

Postfix uses [SASL](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) for authentication, and can have either the Cyrus SASL library, or Dovecot as backends.  Neither have a REST API, but if you're crafty with a script language you might be able to write a daemon that speaks the Dovecot authentication protocol to Postfix, and queries your PHP application for passwords.

Alternatively, Cyrus SASL has a SQL plugin.  You might try to modify this plugin to talk to your application.

Comment: Dovecot has a SQL backend as well, so if the hashing algorithm can be expressed in SQL, then that would be a good option.